# Вопрос по gulp 4

Tags: html, css, gulp, gulp4

Часто замечаю что в галпе когда пишут задачи, в конце пишут не стандартный, например: 
gulp.task('default', gulp.series([список задач]));
А через экспорт, типо дефолтную задачу запускают так: exports.default = defaultTask

Подскажите пожалуйста, обязательно ли это? Или это просто альтернатива стандартному запуску задач?